# Get a real device camera resolution (i.e. Megapixels) in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm trying to get the resolution camera of a physical device using Unity 2018 and C#, so I create a 3D object cube and I attach in it this script:

```
IEnumerator CameraResolution()
{
    WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    Debug.Log("Number of web cams connected: " + devices.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
    {
        string camName = devices[i].name;
        Debug.Log("selected webcam name is " + camName);

        if (backCam == null)
            backCam = new WebCamTexture();

        backCam.deviceName = camName;

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = backCam;

        if (!backCam.isPlaying)
            backCam.Play();
        float h = backCam.height;
        float w = backCam.width;
        Debug.Log("The camera pixel is: " + (w / h) );
        yield return null;
    }
    backCam.Stop();
}
```

However I got a wrong result when I lunch this script:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXfCr.jpg)

I want to get example a result like this:
The camera pixel is: 64MP.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68250750/how-get-my-smartphone-device-camera-megapixel

Comment: There is no solution in the post, also the comment is not helpful for my case, I saw it before I post this question.

Comment: Ah, that other post isn't by you? The main is similar, the code is similar. Very odd.

Comment: @mjwills the code is not similar but basically exactly the same lol ^^ OP what is your target platform? As I mentioned on the linked questionbon certain platforms e.g. iOs the camera resolution is limited no matter what the actual resolution could deliver

Answer (score 1):

Some flaws in your code:

By logging

```
w / h
```

you will no nothing but the ratio between width and height.

Rather log e.g.

```
Debug.Log($"The camera resolution is {w} x {h} pixels", this);
```

---

Further you are always only creating one single `WebCamTexture` via the default constructor which automatically uses the default camera device and thus always the same resolution.

Note these points from the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-deviceName.html)

> This only has an effect when set while the camera is **not running**.

-> you are starting the texture once and then never stop it until the full loop is already done.

> Note: if you want to use WebCamTexture to get the camera stream from device connected through Unity Remote, then you must initalize it through the constructor. It's not possible to change device using WebCamTexture.deviceName from regular devices to remote devices and vice versa.

-> instead of setting the name rather create s new texture through the constructor then you should be save

What you rather want to do is e.g.

```
IEnumerator CameraResolution()
{
    WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    Debug.Log("Number of web cams connected: " + devices.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
    {
        string camName = devices[i].name;
        Debug.Log("selected webcam name is " + camName);

        backCam = new WebCamTexture(camName);

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = backCam;

        backCam.Play();
        float h = backCam.height;
        float w = backCam.width;
        
        Debug.Log($"The {camName} camera resolution is {w} x {h} pixels", this);
        yield return null;
        backCam.Stop();
        Destroy(backCam);
    }   
}
```

Further if you already know the supported resolution you can try and set [`requestedHeight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-requestedHeight.html) and [`requestedWidth`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-requestedWidth.html) before starting the playback.

Comment: I got now different value from each camera, thank you, but how can I tell the user that his camera is e.g. 64MP, I received in the log 1280 x 720 pixels, this result isn't my device screen resolution ? however I'm looking for my device camera resolution.